# Material UI FilledInput and OutlinedInput components not found under @material-ui/core

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have installed "@material-ui/core": "^1.5.1" and [material-ui-chip-input@next](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input).

On trying to use the material-ui-chip-input component, it throws Module **@material-ui/coreFilledInput** and **@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput** not found.

On looking into node_modules of @material-ui/core, i couldn't find those components. But they are still part of the documentation.

https://material-ui.com/api/filled-input/

https://material-ui.com/api/outlined-input/

Comment: Resolved it using the latest version of @material-ui/core.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by using the latest version of @material-ui/core.